# Eigenvalues on diagonal of triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It can be shown that if a matrix is a triangular matrix then the eigenvalues can be read off as the entries along the diagonal. Does this mean that given any matrix, we can row reduce it to triangular form and read off the eigenvalues along the diagonal? This is demonstrably not (always) true; it seems row reduction distorts information about a matrix's eigenvalues, but it sure got me curious.

Suppose the given matrix, $A$, *initially* was written in triangular form; in that case we could readily read off the eigenvalues along the diagonal. But that very matrix, $A$, obviously is row equivalent to another non-triangular matrix, $B$, so *shouldn't* it be possible to row reduce any given matrix to triangular form and read off the eigenvalues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Row reduction does not preserve the eigenvalues. You can see it by noticing that any invertible matrix (with any eigenvalues of your choice_ is row-reducible to the identity matrix (with all eigenvalues equal to one). Or you can notice that row reduction is achieved by left-multiplying be certain invertible matrices (those realizing the elementary operations); left multiplication by a matrix does not usually preserve eigenvalues.

Eigenvalues are preserved, on the other hand, by similarity (conjugation by an invertible matrix and its inverse). That's why you can always read the eigenvalues from the diagonal of the Jordan form.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I'm fairly new to linear algebra and have thus some remarks: (1) "(with all eigenvalues equal to one)" How can we draw that conclusion? We couldn't read off the eigenvalues after having row reduced a matrix, right? (2) "left multiplication by a matrix does not usually preserve eigenvalues." This seemingly is the central answer to my question, but it isn't as entirely obvious to me as it is you. How is it plain for us that left multiplication by a matrix doesn't preserve eigenvalues?

Comment: First, the identity matrix is a diagonal matrix, and so its eigenvalues are the elements of its diagonal. As for multiplication not preserving the eigenvalues, it is just a fact that the eigenvalues of a product of matrices are usually very different from the eigenvalues of each of the matrices (with of course some exception cases); as the simplest example, consider the product of two diagonal matrices.

Comment: Oh! Ok, so what you were getting at was that an invertible matrix might have eigenvalues, say, {2,4} but row reduction yields a (triangular) matrix with eigenvalue 1 (of some multiplicity ≥ 1); hence row reduction is fruitless.
Very well then, just happens to be that way. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Exactly. And you are welcome :)